# Cache-Control: public,max-age=LONG_TIME response does not work behind HTTP 301 redirect

Tags: http, firefox, web-applications, browser-cache, cache-control

My server is hosting an application which preloads >100 thumbnail images on each page load. The thumbnail images do not change often.

I am trying to make consecutive thumbnail loads faster by using `Cache-Control: public,max-age=MANY_SECONDS` where `MANY_SECONDS` is up to a year.

The thumbnails are requested via a Flask endpoint that looks like this:

```py
@app.route('/api/thumbnail/<string:filename>/<int:max_width>/<int:max_height>/')
def api_thumbnail(filename, max_width, max_height):
    thumb_filename_template = '{filename}_{orig_digest}-{dimensions}-thumb.png'

    # [...] PIL thumbnailing logic [...]

    key = Key(thumb_filename_template.format(
            filename=filename,
            orig_digest=md5_hexdigest_of_original_image,
            dimensions='x'.join([max_width, max_height])
        ))

    # Upload the thumbnail image to Amazon S3
    key.set_contents_from_string(local_thumbnail_file.read())

    redirect(key.generate_url(0, query_auth=False), code=301)
```

I set the `Cache-Control` header to `public,max-age=MANY_SECONDS` for all the `*-thumb.png` keys, still Firefox fires a request against `/api/thumbnail/...` and gets the 301, then a 304 from Amazon S3.

I'm under the impression that 301 responses are cached seemingly for an eternity, and the `Cache-Control` headers for the thumbnail files served from Amazon S3 should allow Firefox to cache the thumbnail files locally for up to a year.

All these *thumbs × 2* requests are really an overhead. I want them cached for an eternity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use a [HTML5 manifest](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) file.